# Meaning of Aquae Sextiae

Tags: vocabulary, place-names

The Battle of Aquae Sextiae is the site where the Teutones and Ambrones were defeated by the Romans under Gaius Marius in 102 BC.

What does this place name in English? It is located in modern-day southern France.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe its modern name is Aix-en-Provence, the original name meaning "the waters of Sextius [Calvinus]"..